# Where should data files be placed when using composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

Composer is very awesome for managing dependencies and makes life so much easier.

However, I am a bit unsure where I should place data files to be used by my composer requirements.

For example, the [Maxmind GeoIP library](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php?source=cc) is something I am using. Because the maxmind databases are provided independently of the PHP library and have a different cycle, there really isn't a way to make it a composer requirement.

Should I add them as packages to my composer.json? Since I have a Satis installation for serving private repos, should I create my own repo for those datafiles?

What is the accepted practice of dealing with vendor databases and datafiles when using composer?

Comment: What command do you run to update the GeoIP library data?

Comment: The command to update the GeoIP library is `composer update`, but there isn't really any way to update the GeoIP library data. At the moment, it's just download the zip and extract it to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage the data via composer, I would suggest to configure them as an own package, which you require on project level.

There is no default workflow for non php parts. Especially databases are rarely managed via composer, as there is no standard for doing migrations.

In my opinion, migration scripts should not be part of composer, because only your application should alter your databases, and only when you want it to, not when you execute composer commands.

The GeoIP datas are a bit different, this is only a kind resource file you use. If I look at attempts regarding java-script and similar, its common to have a separate composer package for them. So like I said first, add the data in an own package, which you can maintain separate from the GeoIp Library